# How to find the last element in an under capacity array?

Tags: java, arrays, null, capacity

Say my array is defined like this:

```
int [] p = new int[10];
p[0] = 1;
p[1] = 4;
p[2] = 7;
```

I know I could use an ArrayList and not worry about resizing, but I just want to know how one could find the index of the last element (7) in that array. This is what I tried and it was failing because obviously I can't compare int to null. how else would you go about doing this?

```
int tail=0;
for(int i= 0; i < p.length; i++){
    if(a[i]==null){
       tail= i-1;
       break;
    }

}
```

Comment: `int` array elements are initialized as zeroes.  If all **your** values are positive numbers you can check for 0, otherwise you simply cannot distinguish between default and assigned values.

Comment: well, the other array components would be initialised to zero not null; unless zero would not be entered then the only check you could do is that when you encounter a zero your index will be the previous one.

Comment: When you create an array of a specific type, all its elements are initialized with the default value of that type, zero in this case. Its better to use arraylist instead :)

Comment: There's also the option to use the efficient `Arrays.fill` operation to initialize to any sentry value, such as `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: Even if you could compare an int[] element to null your code would be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out `this code`:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
class IntArrayExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      int[] p = new int[10];
      p[0] = 1;
      p[1] = 4;
      p[2] = 7;
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(p));
      int tail=0;
      for(int i= 0; i < p.length; i++){
        if(p[i]==0){
         tail= i-1;
         System.out.println("tail : " + tail);
         break;
        }
       }
     }
    }
```

OUTPUT:

```
[1, 4, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
tail : 2
```

as you can see where I `print the array`, the `int array` is initialised with `zeros`. The tail is `2` in this case. If you also want to have `elements with the value of zero` in your array and don't want to use `ArrayList`, `initialise all elements to another value (e.g. Integer.MAX_VALUE or Integer.MIN_VALUE)` and then `do your checks accordingly`.

By the way, this line of code is wrong:

```
 if(a[i]==null){
```

not only because of `incomparable types: int and <null>`, but also because your array is called `p` and not `a`. Hope that helps !

Comment: I think "content-wise" your answer is great; but your code example could be better formatted; and violating the Java naming style guide shouldnt happen in "answer" code fragments.

Comment: I improved the formatting, how am I violating the Java naming style so that I fix that as well ?

Comment: intArray is not a good name for class; it should be IntArray (class names do start with uppercase letters) ... or even better IntArrayExample or something alike - the name of the class should always reflect its purpose.

Comment: Ok changed it, thought it might be that :)

Comment: @adrCoder: Thanks for the answer. Yep my array should be `p` not  `a`. It was a typo. Cheers!

Comment: Glad I could be of help. Good luck with your project and don't hesitate to ask more questions. Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize `int` `array` of specific size, it place default value as zero until it is replaced by setting new non zero value.

**Example:**

Array mentioned in question will have default values as below.

```
[1, 4, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Now if you like to find last non-zero value of array following solution can help you achieve it.

Use below mentioned code to get index value.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] p = new int[10];
    p[0] = 1;
    p[1] = 4;
    p[2] = 7;

    System.out.println(getLastFilledIndex(p));

}

private static int getLastFilledIndex(int[] p) {
    for(int i=p.length-1;i>0;i--){
        if(p[i]!=0){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**
2

As shown above code will iterate from last index untill it found non-zero value and return the index.

Comment: Shouldn't answers be about explaining problems? Do you really think a newbie will can learn much from a few lines of code; without providing any guidance why you do things the way you do them?